# phantomjs low cpu utilization

Tags: phantomjs, wkhtmltopdf

I'm spawning multiple phantomjs.exe process in parallel from c# to generate pdf served from my local iis. When using wkhtmltopdf.exe I can see that my cpu (core i7-4790k) utilization is always high >90% but using phantomjs, cpu utilization is low 30-70%. 
Thus its slower for phantomjs to generate all my pdf compared to wkhtmltopdf. I would like to use phantomjs because it render nicer. How to fix this ?

Comment: Does it take more time?

Comment: yes about double the time

Comment: Perhaps you're not spawning enough processes.